# Construct a smooth curve with length $10$ and enclosing an area $6$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

The problem is the title and when I tried to construct such a curve I found my always obtain an ellipse, but failed to calculate the length of it. Are there any better constructions?
I forget to add a condition.

Comment: Try a simpler shape, like a rectangle. The sums of two consecutive sides would have to be $5$ and their product $6$. So, sides $2$ and $3$ will suffice.

Comment: can we use a rectangle?

Comment: Does "smooth" mean infinitely differentiable, or once differentiable?

Comment: Smooth means infinitely differentiable.

Comment: nooooo infinitely! :(

Comment: I think you should look for a polar curve. Foe example the cardioid $$r=\frac{5}{8}(1-\cos\theta)$$ has length $10$

Comment: @Qurultay -- But the cardioid is not smooth at $\theta = 0$.

Comment: Do you need the curve to be regular? Rectangles can be smoothly parametrized, but not regularly. An ellipse should work, but if you want an explicit expression for it then it will involve inverting elliptic integrals.